# Kibana Mapping conflict How to make sure this error wont get repeated

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to kibana we are using Aws es 5.5.  i have setuped the dashboards yesterday which are working fine but today morning when i see all dashboards are empty with out no data. i found it was due to Mapping conflict. In google i found one Answer was to reindex the data. how can we prevent in future this type of errors.

Any Answers would be greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have the same field twice  with not the same mapping, for example gender define as string in one place and in other place define as number.
You need to check it and prevent it next time